# PostGIS ST_Transform results shifted by about 25 metres

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I have a road network downloaded from OSM and imported into PostGIS with pgrouting. I convert it with a specific local EPSG `ST_Transform(geom, 26717)`, but the result is shifted about 20 metres to the east and 5 to the north. The new coordinates are instead equivalent to a different local EPSG 2029. The only real difference between these two seems to be NAD27 vs NSD27(76).

Example: 
https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=26717&x=-79.3545864&y=43.7094892 returns x=632549.24, y=4840701.20

but

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(43.7094892, -79.3545864), 4326), 26717))
```

returns

```
SRID=26717;POINT(632566.193912585 4840706.93374429)
```

I'm at a loss what could be causing it or how to resolve...

Using PostGIS version
`POSTGIS="2.5.1 r17027" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.7.0-CAPI-1.11.0 673b9939" PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018" GDAL="GDAL 2.3.1, released 2018/06/22" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.0" RASTER`
on Amazon RDS Postgres 11.4-R1

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're not misreading something?

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-79.3545864, 43.7094892), 4326), 26717)) 

"SRID=26717;POINT(632549.238889373 4840701.2020248)"
```

Comment: Interesting. What is your environment? I have now tried a few different ones, and I get your correct result on: 
- Amazon RDS Postgres 9.6 with PostGIS 2.3.7
- Localhost Postgres 11.4 with PostGIS 3.0.0alpha4dev

And my incorrect result on:
- Amazon RDS 11.4 PostGIS 2.5.1 
- Amazon RDS 11.4 PostGIS 2.4.5
- Localhost Postgres 11.4 with PostGIS 2.5.2

Comment: Slight correction: with PostGIS 3.0.0alpha4dev, I end up with a slightly different answer, but it's within a few metres `SRID=26717;POINT(632546.971443493 4840700.42750151)`

Comment: But 3.0 still has a problem converting between the two PCS themselves. While the transformation from EPSG4326 seems to work better, the outputs are the same as the inputs when tranforming from 26717 to 2029 or vice versa.. `select st_astext(st_transform(st_geomfromtext('POINT(632500 4840700)',26717), 2029));` and `select st_astext(st_transform(st_geomfromtext('POINT(632500 4840700)',2029), 26717));` both yield exactly `POINT(632500 4840700)`

Comment: "PostgreSQL 10.9 (Ubuntu 10.9-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit"

"POSTGIS="2.4.3 r16312" PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.7.0-CAPI-1.11.0 673b9939" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.4.0, released 2018/12/14" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" RASTER"